# How do I manually connect to a WPA2 EAP-TLS school network using cloudpath on linux?

Tags: networking, arch-linux, ssl-certificate, private-key, wpa2

I’ve been trying to join my school’s wifi network with little success.
Our school uses Cloudpath Enrollment System (used to be called Xpressconnect or something). All devices have to install and run an executable to be able to join the network. I am running arch, but the installer only supports Windows, MacOS and iOS.
I’ve asked the IT department for some manual configuration instructions, but they said something like “...there aren’t many people using Linux, so it would be a waste of time. We just don’t support it.” and that they can’t help me. They were also against the idea of manually giving me the certificates. (if that’s even possible)
The only way to get the installer is to join the school enrolment wifi, and download an exe or .zip file. They are hosted on a website “powered by cloudpath” and have unique names/variables.
What the installer does (I’m pretty sure) is just download/deploy certificates from the school network, as the program just spits out errors if not connected to the school enrolment wifi.
After doing some poking around in a friend’s mac’s keychain, I know that connecting to the network requires an RSA private key. (WPA2 Enterprise EAP-TLS)
This part has stumped me. I am unsure whether I should continue trying extracting a private key from a windows/Mac machine (both keys were ‘non-exportable’ when I tried) or I should just try follow each step in the debug log and manually download my certificates.
I have access to a windows machine too, and am wondering if there’s a way to extract non-exportable private keys? All the methods I’ve found for this are either 6-7 years old or scams.
The Mac .zip file contains a URL in an XML file ending in “generateCertificate” with three variables at the end: ${EnrollmentGUID}, ${AuthToken} and ${csr}. I have located the information for the first two (stored in a session.properties), but I can’t find anything to do with csr in the whole directory.
How would you suggest I go about this?

Comment: Don't steal your friend's private key. It's pretty clear this system has each client device generate a public/private key pair in secure local storage, and then uses the public key and the student's identity to generate a matching cert unique to that user, and then use that user-cert (and the matching private key) as the authentication credentials for the WPA2-Enterprise, EAP-TLS network.

Some versions of Arris/Ruckus Cloudpath do seem to have support for Linux clients, or even configuration paths for "generic" client, but it's unclear why your school isn't doing it.